# Gravar endereço por coordenadas e pegar no maps do google

Tags: sql-server, google-maps

Sei que o google disponibiliza sua api para mapas. Gostaria de gravar endereços mas também as coordenadas, que quando o usuário fosse ler essas coordenadas, já mostrasse na tela dele ou no App dele, o mapa do endereço buscado. Como pego as coordenadas a partir de um endereço dado? Tipo:

> Av. Nossa Senhora de Copacabana, 256 - Cep: xx.xxx-999

Isso é apenas um endereço aleatório, apenas um exemplo.

Comment: Utilize a API Geocode do maps: [API Endereço to Coordenadas](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 3):

O que você quer fazer é utilizar o [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?csw=1). A forma de utilizar vai depender da linguagem que você optar. Como não específicou, segue um exemplo básico em JS.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
    "address": inputAddress
}, function(results) {
    console.log(results[0].geometry.location); //LatLng
});
```

Caso utilize .NET, sugiro dar uma olhada nesse [pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geocoding.Google/) que trás bastante funções de forma bem prática.

Vale ressaltar que o geocoding é limitado a 2500 requisições por dia e que de acordo com os termos de uso, você deve utiliza-ló sempre junto ao Google Maps.

Comment: Não especifiquei por ser algo bem genérico, mas hoje utilizo c# e xamarin e xamarin.forms